# Do threads ever commit suicide or stop running

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

When will this thread stop running and stop existing? Will it stop running immediately after printing the number `10`? Is it available for garbage collection immediately after printing `10`? Or must I explicitly interrupt it or something?

```
Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (int i =0; i<=10; i++) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
};
new Thread(counter).start();
```

Comment: You shouldn't interrupt anything. In your case the thread exits once the `run` method finishes its execution.

Comment: Falling off the end of `run()` is the same as falling out of `main()`, which are pretty much equivalent to calling `System.exit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thread doesn't commit *suicide*. It simply terminates or gets aborted (say, killed).

There is an important factor that justifies the usage of a so brutal term, *killing*, for process and threads: their state is not saved and transactional integrity is not directly guaranteed unless you have another mechanism.

In your case, the thread will simply print from 1 to 10 and terminate, being garbaged the next time GC runs.

Nothing more.

Comment: Yes, it is more analogous to them being "murdered" (by the GC) than them "committing suicide"

Comment: Why not *collected in peace*? :D

Comment: @Stallman please post it as a question, we'll be glad to answer with proper text space